# How to compile Qt 5.8 statically with PostgreSQL plugin in VS2015

Tags: c++, postgresql, static, compilation, qt5.8

Can anybody who may have any idea compiling Qt 5.8 Open Source statically with PostgreSQL support on Windows. I tried all the options known to me including the below. I'm using qt 5.8 sources on Windows 10 x64.

```
configure -opensource -confirm-license -debug-and-release -static -platform win32-msvc2015 -nomake examples -nomake tests -sql-psql PSQL_LIBS="C:\PSQL\9.6\lib\libpq.lib" -I C:\PSQL\9.6\include\libpq -I C:\PSQL\9.6\include -L C:\PSQL\9.6\lib\libpq.lib
```

After running the config above, I seem to be getting the below:

> Note: Using static linking will disable the use of dynamically
>   loaded plugins. Make sure to import all needed static plugins,
>   or compile needed modules into the library.
>   ERROR: Feature 'sql-psql' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'libs.psql' failed.
>   Check config.log for details.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What does `config.log` say?

Comment: It's quite log but It's here:   http://pastebin.com/nmrEFLrs

Comment: I cannot see anything pertinent in there, sorry. Maybe ask Qt?

Answer (score 2):

That worked for me while building Qt 5.9.1

```
configure -prefix <your parameters> ^
PSQL_LIBS="D:\PostgreSQL\9.6\lib\libpq.lib" ^
-I D:\PostgreSQL\9.6\include ^
-L D:\PostgreSQL\9.6\lib
```