# Error with static compilation Qt with postgresql driver

Tags: postgresql, qt, compiler-errors

I have installed through Mainteinance Tool Qt 5.12.5 and the sources. I have the next directories:

```
C:\Qt\5.12.5\Src 
C:\Qt\Tools\mingw730_32\
C:\Qt\Tools\mingw730_64\
```

On the other hand, I have read that downloable Postgres version is compiled with MSVC, and I must to compile my own version. I have do it following [link](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/building-postgresql-with-msys2-and-mingw-under-windows/), and now I have a postgresql version in `c:\pgsql`

Finally I have added `c:\pgsql` to user Path

Next step, I have opened PowerShell in Admin mode and I´ve gone to `C:\Qt\5.12.5\Src\`.

Next, set the env path for this PowerShell session:
`$env:Path += ";C:\Qt\Tools\mingw730_64\bin\;C:\Qt\5.12.5\Src;C:\pgsql\include\;C:\pgsql\lib\;C:\pgsql\bin\"` (setting the pgsql path again....)

After that, I execute `configure.bat` like that:

```
configure -v -static -release -static-runtime -platform win32-g++ -prefix C:\Qt\5.12.5\Estatico\ -opensource -confirm-license -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -opengl desktop -no-openssl -opensource -confirm-license -skip webengine -make libs -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests -sql-psql
```

But I have get this error:

```
ERROR: Feature 'sql-psql' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'libs.psql' failed.
```

Searching in `config.log` I can read those lines:

```
loaded result for library config.qtbase_sqldrivers.libraries.psql
Trying source 0 (type pkgConfig) of library psql ...
pkg-config use disabled globally.
  => source produced no result.
Trying source 1 (type psqlConfig) of library psql ...
pg_config not found.
  => source produced no result.
Trying source 2 (type psqlEnv) of library psql ...
None of [liblibpq.dll.a liblibpq.a libpq.dll.a libpq.a libpq.lib] found in [] and global paths.
  => source produced no result.
Trying source 3 (type psqlEnv) of library psql ...
  => source failed condition '!config.win32'.
test config.qtbase_sqldrivers.libraries.psql FAILED
```

What can I do or what is the properly way to do that?
Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

There are similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42897652/how-to-compile-qt-5-8-statically-with-postgresql-plugin-in-vs2015) but it hasn´t been solved, and those question ask about Visual Studio.

I want to compile it under mingw.

<strike>The solution suggested by @Soheil Armin doesn´t work too</strike>
The solution suggested by @Soheil Armin works fine, but I need to delete the entire source tree and reinstall it as he suggested. If not, a new configure won't work.
Also, the `^` character can be saved:

```
configure <your parameters> 
PSQL_LIBS="C:\pgsql\lib\libpq.a" 
-I "C:\pgsql\include" 
-L "C:\pgsql\lib"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compile Qt 5.8 statically with PostgreSQL plugin in VS2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42897652/how-to-compile-qt-5-8-statically-with-postgresql-plugin-in-vs2015)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly define library paths of Postgres.

```
configure <your parameters> ^
PSQL_LIBS="C:\pgsql\lib\libpq.a" ^
-I "C:\pgsql\include" ^
-L "C:\pgsql\lib"
```

Comment: Thank you, but It doesn´t work for me. But I can see I haven´t libpq.lib, only libpq.a and libpq.dll. I´ll update the question

Comment: Ok. just use **libpq.a** as you are using mingw. Don't forget to clean configuration before retry:
git submodule foreach --recursive "git clean -dfx"

Comment: Thank you again. It doesn´t work too. I haven´ t dowlnloaded source from Git...do I need any cleanup of configure even? If yes, how could I do it?

Comment: You can make/nmake distclean but sometime it does not work. It's better to remove the whole directory and extract it again from the archive.

Comment: Solved. The worst is that I have had to reinstall the sources each time I was wrong. It took me a long time. If not, a new configure didnt't work.  The distclean doesn' t work too. Also, is not necesary write "^" symbol in the string of options. Thank you!